# Directional derivatives and limit rules

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am having some problems understanding directional derivatives and limit rules. I was hoping someone might be able to help.

Basically, the result is the $f'(x, -a)$ = $-f'(x,a)$. To show this (after some manipulations, we have:

**(1)** $f'(x, -a) = \lim\limits_{(-h) \to 0} \frac{f(x+(-h)a) - f(x)}{(-h)} = -f'(x,a)$ **(2)**

I had two questions:

1. Firstly, can I intepret the result as **(1)** the instantenous rate of change in the direction opposite to $a$ is equal to **(2)** the instantaneous rate of change in the opposite direction to $a$?
2. I don't understand the second equality. When I write out $-f(x,a)$ according to the definition, I have:

$-f'(x, a) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{-f(x+ ha) + f(x)}{h}$

It's not obvious to me why the two are equal. Is it because $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}$ is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{(-h) \to 0}$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The equality that you wish to prove means that the instantaneous rate of change in the opposite direction of $a$ is the symetric of the instantaneous rate of change in the direction of $a$. And the answer to your final question is affirmative.

Comment: Thank you José Carlos. Just so I am clear, is it correct to say, in general, that $\lim\limits_{(-h) \to 0} \frac{f(x+(-h)a) - f(x)}{(-h)}$ = $\lim\limits_{(h) \to 0} \frac{f(x+ha) - f(x)}{(h)}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.